# Por que no me genera los items en el HTML?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Tengo un inconveniente con React. Me traigo los datos de un **Firestore**, y mostrando en consola me llegan todos los datos sin problema, pero al momento de implantarlos en el HTML no me genera ni si quiera el `Li` o el componente que yo declare:

```
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';


export default function ProductList({data}){

    console.log(data);
    // Me muestra mis objetos, los datos llegan
        return (
            <section className='productsContainer'>
                {data.forEach(function(item){
                    <li> <ProductCard brand={item.data.brand} model={item.data.model} /> </li>
                })}
            </section>
        );
};
```

`brand` y `model` son solo dos strings que en `productCard` los coloco por `prop` en un `h2` y `h3` respectivamente.

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. en español, cuando codificas esto `{item.data.brand}` es porque estas tratando de acceder al elemento `item`, el cual tiene un objeto `data` que a su vez tienen una propiedad `brand`, yo pensaría que tal vez el objeto `data` esta de más, pues no se como es la estructura interna de `data`, intenta `{item.brand}` y `{item.model}`, también si puedes agregar el resultado de `console.log(data)` editando tu pregunta, saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El bucle forEach no esta retornando nada, por lo que tu item se pierde, para solucionarlo agrégale un return

```
console.log(data);
// Me muestra mis objetos, los datos llegan
    return (
        <section className='productsContainer'>
            {data.forEach(function(item){
                return <li> <ProductCard brand={item.data.brand} model={item.data.model} /> </li>
            })}
        </section>
    );
};
```